# Showing images from xml link via xslt

Tags: html, xml, xslt

Basically I want images to be shown in my table if I have image links in my xml. I know I'm supposed to use attribute but whatever I tried, nothing worked.

XML

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="catalog.xsl"?>
<catalog>
    <cd>
        <title>Empire Burlesque</title>
        <picture url="https://www.planwallpaper.com/static/images/Winter-Tiger-Wild-Cat-Images.jpg" />
        <artist>Bob Dylan</artist>
        <country>USA</country>
        <company>Columbia</company>
        <price>10.90</price>
        <year>1985</year>
    </cd>
    <cd>
        <title>Hide your heart</title>
        <picture url="http://i.istockimg.com/cms/resources/images/HomePage/Tiles/US_March2016/SilenceAndNoise_Signature_78262195.jpg" />
        <artist>Bonnie Tyler</artist>
        <country>UK</country>
        <company>CBS Records</company>
        <price>9.90</price>
        <year>1988</year>
    </cd>
</catalog>
```

XSLT

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:template match="/">
  <html>
  <body>
  <h2>My CD Collection</h2>
  <table border="1">
    <tr bgcolor="#9acd32">
      <th>Title</th>
      <th>Artist</th>
    </tr>
    <xsl:for-each select="catalog/cd">
    <tr>
      <td><xsl:value-of select="title"/></td>
      <td><xsl:value-of select="artist"/></td>
    </tr>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </table>
  </body>
  </html>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

So I want instead of my links, the actual images to be shown. How would I do that? As far as I got, I get X's instead of the actual images for some reason. Any ideas why?

I tried Tim C's code and it slightly works. In his link it works but when I run it on my pc, it doesn't show the images anymore

I checked it on every browser, both windows and linux and same problem. No images appear using Tim's code. I even uploaded it on a server and the problem persists. The photos look like they are corupted or something. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You use the `img` tag in HTML, with the `src` attribute to show an attribute, so if you were in a template that matched `picture` you would do it like this

```
<xsl:template match="picture">
    <img src="{@url}" />
</xsl:template>
```

The curly braces are known as "Attribute Value Templates". The expression inside the curly braces is evaluated to produce a value.

Try this XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="html" doctype-public="XSLT-compat" omit-xml-declaration="yes" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" />

<xsl:template match="/">
  <html>
  <body>
  <h2>My CD Collection</h2>
  <table border="1">
    <tr bgcolor="#9acd32">
      <th>Title</th>
      <th>Artist</th>
      <th>Image</th>
    </tr>
    <xsl:for-each select="catalog/cd">
    <tr>
      <td><xsl:value-of select="title"/></td>
      <td><xsl:value-of select="artist"/></td>
      <td>
          <xsl:apply-templates select="picture" />
      </td>
    </tr>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </table>
  </body>
  </html>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="picture">
    <img src="{@url}" />
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Note that if the input XML had multiple pictures for a cd, this would should all of them. To show just the first picture in this case, do `<xsl:apply-templates select="picture[1]" />`

Also note it might be preferred to specify a height and width for your images too, although you would need to amend the XML for that, but you add the attributes to the image in the same was as the url.

```
<xsl:template match="picture">
    <img src="{@url}" height="{@height}px" width="{@width}px" />
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: I'm getting some X's instead of photos for some reason

Comment: I am not sure why that is. You can see it in action at http://xsltransform.net/bnnZX6. Click the "HTML" tab in the bottom left-hand corner and you will see the images of a tiger, and a little fluffy chicken.

Comment: I see them though when I run the code on InternetExplorer (cause I dont know how to run it in Chrome), instead of images, I get some X's like it can't find the photos or something

Comment: Yes, it is working fine for me. What happens when you manually create an HTML page with the images in?

Comment: The images appear properly, just like they should. Only when I open the xml, they aren't working

Comment: Are you viewing the XML simply by double-clicking it, or are you viewing it via a local web server by an http request (i.e by navigating to something like http://localhost/test.xml)?

Comment: I only click it, it opens up in Intenret Explorer and that's it but I tried upping it on a server too and I get the exact same result

Comment: If the images definitely exist, and you can see them when you paste the image URL into your browser, then I am afraid I am getting short of ideas. Having said that, I have made a small tweak to my XSLT to add an `xsl:output` statement, but I can't image for one moment that will make a difference.

Comment: Yea, no change. I have no idea what could be the problem. The images do exist. The HTML generated code works properly... :/

Comment: This works if I make the image links to be text between tags and not short tags. Could you tell me how to apply the image thing on this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36403847/generic-xslt-that-transforms-xml-into-html-table-with-rules ?